# ubuntu git init permission denied

Tags: git, ubuntu

I guess I have a problem with my rights.
I have a nearly new Ubuntu 14.04 installed and just configured my vhost to display my little html project.
The new site has no problem to work correctly in the Firefox.

But now I want to initialize a new git repo and failed.
When I type inside /var/www/html

```
git init
```

I get this error

```
/var/www/html/.git: permission denied
```

My /var/www has these permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 13 www-data www-data 4096 Jan  4 18:48 html/
```

When I type

```
ssh-add -l
```

my id_rsa(RSA) is displayed correctly.

I have no clue what else I missing here. :-(

Comment: You don't have permission to write in that folder and it's not a folder I recommend adding read and write for everyone.  You could add yourself to the www-data group `usermod -a -G www-data your_username`

Comment: When I type (ls -l /var/www/html) the result is www-data www-data

Comment: @Ding I can't use (usermod -a -G www-data) because it always ends up that I will see the help info of that command.

Comment: Compare to change user permission, I personally think maybe it's better for you to change config of apache or nginx, to use another folder, which you have write permission.

Comment: @Eric What do mean with that? Isn't the /var/www folder the standard folder for the apache? I hadn't change the apache conf now.

Comment: @Tipo In apache `DocumentRoot` define the document root, you can define another root for a specific virtual host, I think google & apache doc will provide more details if you want to try in this way.

Answer (score 6):

Your `/var/www` folder permissions only permit writing files for the `www-data` user and members of the `www-data` group.  You can add yourself to the `www-data` group with the following command

```
usermod -a -G www-data your_username
```

If you're logged in over SSH you will need to **logout** and then back on.

That should allow you to write files in that folder without having to give everyone write permissions.  Doing so is not a good idea on a production server.

Comment: ok, with sudo I can commit this command.
But this has no effect for initialize with git.
Furthermore I have a new problem or maybe the same ... I can't create a new folder with mkdir inside /var/www

Comment: Try logging off and back on.  I had to after adding myself to the group and everything worked.

Comment: @Eric For security reasons I recommend against those permissions but that would work.

Comment: @Ding Yes, but it's op's local simple html project, I think security is ...  , let him care about security when deploy to a real server.

Comment: "If you're logged in over SSH you will need to logout and then back on." why did I never know this?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be having permission to access the directory you are working on because it is owned by root. Check if it has a LOCK icon. If it does use:

```
sudo chown <username>:<username> <name_of_working_directory>
```

where username is your username. This changes ownership and grants you permission to access the folder and push to git.