# Permission denied for git init

Tags: git, permissions

**git init** can't run in `/var/www/html/wp`
I do as Ding says in the web.

[usermod -a -G www-data username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889395/ubuntu-git-init-permission-denied/27889459#27889459)

```
usermod -a -G www-data debian8
```

[image]

[image]
It takes no effect at all.
Why can't I run **git init** in my `/var/www/html/wp`?

Comment: it isn't lying to you, your permissions are denied, so show us the current permissions of that directory. do an "ll" of that directory which which user and groups can use it.  Also, he says to relogin, if you're using ssh.  Did you do that?

Comment: /var/www/html is on my local pc.

Comment: it seems like your ll command didn't show exactly what I wanted.  What are the permissions on the folder itself?  Does it have write privileges for the *group*?

Comment: Please see my `ls -all` attachment.

Comment: Your group has no write privilege. One way of doing it is to use g+w with chmod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo chmod -R  g+w  /var/www/html/wp

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the umask in your .profile in your home directory:

```
# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
# umask 022
umask 002
```

What this does is set the initial perms for any new directories or files that you create.

New directories will get 775 (drwxrwxr-x), vs default 755 (drwxr-xr-x). 
Files will get           664 (-rw-rw-r--), vs default 644 (-rw-r--r--).

Depending on your situation, you may want to change it back after running git init.