# How can i connect Git and Github

Tags: git, github

For connecting both git and github. First I entered user mail and username and later created a folder in the git folder and located newly created path in git bash and then I entered `git init` then am getting PERMISSION DENIED. Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied for git init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546140/permission-denied-for-git-init)

Comment: This error has nothing to do with github and is entirely to do with where you are running `git init` or even how. Are you on windows (you said git bash)? If so, try running it as an administrator.

Comment: You'll need to include more information about your setup and the error message. As it is, there are far too many possible problems to be able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS, but the general answer is:

- First make sure you can create a folder (`mkdir test`)
- Once that is working, *then* you can use `git init myNewRepo`
- And then you can start linking it to GitHub:

  ```
  cd myNewRepo
  git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/<myNewRepo>
  ```