# git init: Permission Denied

Tags: git, permissions, centos

I cannot initialize a git repository in a directory outside of my home directory even though I have full permission to the directory (**drwxrwxr-x**).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889395/ubuntu-git-init-permission-denied) post but it doesn't apply to my case since I'm trying to set up the repository for a simple application directory.

Comment: Which operative system are you using?

Comment: I'm using CentOS

Comment: You probably have extra security (SELinux) enabled, and that extra security is denying the permissions. That's what security is all about, after all: making sure nobody can get any work done. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drwxrwxr-x means the folder is writable for the owner or the group.

If your user is not the owner or part of the group of that folder... that would trigger a permission denied.

But if this is done over an SSH session and SELinux is involved, see if [this example](https://github.com/razy-dev/docs/wiki/Setup-gitolite-on-SELinux) can help

```
# git repository user
adduser -d /data/git

# set SELinux policy
semanage fcontext -a -t user_home_dir_t /data/git
semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/data/git/.ssh(/.*)?"
restorecon -R -v /data/git/.ssh
```

Creating the user might not be needed in your case, but the [semmanage commands](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files-persistent_changes_semanage_fcontext) might help.